# Need help implementing Karatsuba algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, multiplication, largenumber

First a little background:
- I'm a first time poster, a student in university (not in programming).
- This is not a homework question, I'm only doing this for fun.
- My programming experience consists of one semester (3 months) of C++, and some QBasic in high school.
- Yes I have looked at the GMP and Bignum libraries; it's very difficult to learn stuff from raw codes, especially without understanding of the programmers' intent. Besides I want to learn how to do it for myself.

I'm coding a multiplication function for arbitrarily large integers. I'm using character arrays to represent these numbers, with a + or - at the end to serve as sentinel (eg. "12345+", "31415-").

I'm currently implementing the Karatsuba algorithm. The problem is that with the recursion and dynamic memory assignments, the function is 5 times slower than the naive method.
I could use some hints on how to reduce the running time.

```
char* dam(char* one, char* two){            // Karatsuba method

    char* zero = intochar(0, 0);
    int size_a = char_size(one) - 1;
    int size_b = char_size(two) - 1;

    if(compare(one, zero) == 0 || compare(two, zero) == 0)
        return zero;                        // if either array is zero, product is zero
    delete[] zero;

    if(size_a < 4 && size_b < 4)            // if both numbers are 3 digits or less, just return their product
        return multiplication(one, two);
                                            // is the product negative?
    bool negative = one[size_a] == two[size_b]? false : true;
    int digits = size_a > size_b ? size_a : size_b;
    digits += digits & 1;                   // add one if digits is odd
    int size = digits / 2 + 1;              // half the digits plus sentinel

    char* a, *b;                            // a and b represent one and two but with even digits
    if(size_a != digits)
        a = pad_char(one, digits - size_a); // pad the numbers with leading zeros so they have even digits
    else
        a = copy_char(one);
    if(size_b != digits)
        b = pad_char(two, digits - size_b);
    else
        b = copy_char(two);

    char* a_left = new char[size];          // left half of number a
    char* a_rite = new char[size];          // right half of number a
    char* b_left = new char[size];
    char* b_rite = new char[size];
    memcpy(a_left, a, size - 1);
    a_left[size - 1] = a[digits];
    memcpy(a_rite, a + size - 1, size);
    memcpy(b_left, b, size - 1);
    b_left[size - 1] = b[digits];
    memcpy(b_rite, b + size - 1, size);
    delete[] a;
    delete[] b;

    char* p0 = dam(a_left, b_left);         // Karatsuba product = p1*10^n + (p0+p2-p1)*10^(n/2) + p2
    char* p2 = dam(a_rite, b_rite);
    deduct(a_left, a_rite);
    deduct(b_left, b_rite);
    char* p1 = dam(a_left, b_left);
    char* p3 = intochar(0, digits - 1);     // p3 = p0 + p2 - p1
    append(p3, p0);                         // append does naive addition
    append(p3, p2);
    deduct(p3, p1);
    delete[] a_left;
    delete[] a_rite;
    delete[] b_left;
    delete[] b_rite;

    int sum_size = 2 * digits;              // product of two numbers can have a maximum of n1 + n2 digits
    char* sum = new char[sum_size + 1];
    memset(sum, 0, sum_size);
    if(negative)
        sum[sum_size] = '-';
    else
        sum[sum_size] = '+';

    char* left = extend_char(p0, digits, false);        // extend returns a new array with trailing zeros
    char* mid = extend_char(p3, size - 1, false);
    append(sum, left);
    append(sum, mid);
    append(sum, p2);
    delete[] p0;
    delete[] p1;
    delete[] p2;
    delete[] p3;
    delete[] left;
    delete[] mid;

    return sum;}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Karatsuba is a nice algorithm, and not too hard to program. If you're only doing it for fun, it's even not a bad idea to work in base 10 -- it slows you down terribly, but it slows down the naive implementation too, so you still have a basis for comparing the two methods.

However, you absolutely must abandon the idea of allocating and freeing your workspace dynamically at every node of the recursion tree. You just can't afford it. You must allocate the required workspace at the start of the computation, and handle your pointers intelligently so that every level of the tree gets the workspace it needs without having to allocate it.

Also, it makes no sense to test for negative products at every level. Just do that at the top level, and work exclusively with positive numbers during the calculation.

Not that it's relevant to your question, but whenever I see something like

```
bool negative = one[size_a] == two[size_b]? false : true;
```

my heart shrinks a little. Think of all those wasted pixels! I respectfully suggest:

```
bool negative = one[size_a] != two[size_b] ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Though I have no idea how to actually implement that... The intro to prog. class I took ended just short of dynamic memory. I pretty much have to learn the whole concept by myself, hence the crazy allocations everywhere (hey at least I remembered to free them LOL). I will change the negative flag accordingly.

Comment: @sth128: Self taught dynamic memory?  Gutsy!  That deserves a good job on doing it right!  You'll want to find a tutorial on `structs`/`classes`, and then one on using `std::string`/`std::vector`

Comment: @Mooing: You don't need all that. You just need to increment/decrement a global pointer by the right amount when you enter/leave a recusrive call. No structs/classes needed, no std::whatever.

Comment: No, but they'd be _incredibly_ handy for what he's doing.  Technically he doesn't even need the heap.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine the slowdown might actually be the allocations.  Replace these with local fixed size buffers and I'd imagine you'll see a decent speed increase.  Or using a custom pool allocator.  But I think that if you're crafty, much of this can be done in place.

Also, if you pass the length of the strings to the functions, you save yourself an iteration to find the length each time.

(also it's spelled "right").

Comment: I cannot use fixed size (do you mean static?) arrays. The K method dictates splitting of these numbers into two halves with each iteration. Also using a static array would arbitrarily limit the size of numbers I can multiply.  As for "right", I chose "rite" because it has the same # of letters as "left" so the code looks nicer...

Comment: You could try using variable-size stack arrays, e.g. "`char a_left[size];`"  I don't remember if this is technically valid C++98 but it works with a lot of compilers.

Comment: C++ cannot declare a static array with a variable integer unless it's constant. But C++ cannot change the value of a constant variable. In any case MS visual C++ compiler (what I'm using) won't do it...

Comment: @sth128: MSVC will do it with the `_alloca` function.

Comment: @sth128: I just programmed a karatsuba algorithm for my bignum object, and did some quick math, and by estimate, it's only faster than the nieve when I have more than 2000ish decimal digits.  The problem with the big-O notation is it leaves out the constants, making algorithmic comparisons tricky.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Funny you should say that. I'm bench marking various modifications to my multiplication code using 20,000! (factorial, not surprised). And yes, my factorial code is also slow as hell... One step at a time I guess.**edit** On closer inspection you wrote 2,000, not 20,000... Ah well also good news cuz 20000! is in the 7000+ digit range.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of spelled-out decimal values is imposing a great deal of overhead.  Karatsuba multiplication is only going to beat long multiplication for numbers that are *huge* relative to the machine register size, and you really want each primitive multiply to be doing as much work as possible.

I recommend you redesign your data structure such that this:

```
if(size_a < 4 && size_b < 4)
    return multiplication(one, two);
```

can become something like this:

```
if(size_a == 1 && size_b == 1)
    return box(int64_t(one[0]) * two[0]);
```

where the type of `one[0]` is `int32_t`, perhaps.  This is what GMP is doing with its `mp_limb_t` arrays.

Comment: I hoped that that's what the `multiplication(one, two);` was doing under the covers.  If not, his "nieve" method is probably using the "multiplication" function as well (for the entire thing), which means this doesn't explain the slowness.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what int32_t is... How it is different from regular (32bit) signed int? Also, in your case would one[0] be more than 9? Currently I'm representing a single digit with each byte of the char array.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: My naive function "Multiplication" does single digit shift and add. Basically, find a[i] * b[j] then add to the sum. Naive method means "what would a 5 year old do"...

Comment: @sth128: `int32_t` is the same as a `signed int` on your computer.  However, `signed int` is not guaranteed to be 32 bits on all computers.  `int32_t` is.

Comment: @sth128: Zach is recommending using an array of `int`/`int64_t` instead of characters representing decimal digits.  You're doing everything in base 10.  He's recommending using base 4294967296 or higher.  He's right that it's _MUCH_ faster.  Though for newer coders I would recommend base 1000000000 instead.

Comment: @Mooning Duck: Sorry I'm a bit slow (like my program!) here's what I understood from your suggestion: By using base 2^32 with an array of integers, any entry will be some huge number (0 - 4 billion) right? And by using C++ multi (*), the operations will be faster. For example if a[0] = 1 and a[1] = 2^32, what number is the array representing in base 10? 1 * 2^32 + 2^32 = 8 billion something?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what I'm recommending.  You'll need to figure out a sensible place to put the sign bit, of course, and it may be appropriate to not use *all* the values of a 32-bit integer type if that makes it easier to deal with overflow.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean writing "the function is 5 times slower"?
Karatsuba is asymptotically faster, not just faster. This means that even a toy implementation of Karatsuba will eventually get faster than the naive multiplication. Did you test speed with 10000-digits numbers?

I know GMP code is not easy to read... but look at [this table extracted from the code](http://gmplib.org/devel/MUL_TOOM22_THRESHOLD.html).
It gives (for different CPUs) the threshold value for Toom-2,2 (Karatsuba). In short terms, the implementation of Karatsuba in GMP is NOT faster than naive implementation for operands smaller than 320 bits (10 x 32-bit registers).

Some questions about your code:

- do you really need char *a, *b ? You delete them before starting computation! ;-)
- are you sure you need to copy the sign to {a,b}_{left,rite}? Did you check if the result is correct with negative operands?
- consider very unbalanced operands... what should you do if size_a * 2 < size_b (or viceversa)?

Next step will be [Toom](http://bodrato.it/toom-cook/), right?

Comment: I tested speeds with a factorial function. The slow down is due to the memory allocation, not so much the number of digits. `*a` & `*b'` aren't really necessary, I am just too lazy to figure out the padding. The `size_a * 2 < size_b` situation is being handled by the `if(compare(a, zero) == 0` statement. Right now I'm just looking for a way to allocate all the memory I need at the beginning instead of doing it on the fly. I don't think I'll be doing Toom implementation any time soon until I've figured out a) how to optimize memory, and b) how to actually use FFT.